# Cosmic variance - Fourier Transform - a few precisions

Tags: galaxy, cosmology, spectra, galaxy-cluster

I have posted initially on physics exchange but none answer, so I try my chance here (I am going to delete the physics exchange one) :

I cite an original report of a colleague :

> If we are interested in power spectrum, we want to estimate the
> variance of the amplitude of the modes $\mathrm{k}$ of our Fourier
> decomposition. If one observes the whole observable Universe and we
> do the Fourier transformation we get a cube whose center is the mode
> $ |\vec{k}| = 0$ which corresponds to the mean value of the observed
> field.
>
> This mode has only one pixel. How do we measure the variance of the
> process at $ |\vec{k}| = 0 $? We can not.
>
> In fact we can but the value of doesn't mean anything because the
> error is infinite. In other words, we have an intrinsic (statistical)
> error which depends on the number of achievements to which we have
> access.
>
> one will be able to consider spheres of sizes $ dk $ between $ [k: k +
> > dk] $ which will contain a number of pixels $ N_ {k} = V_ {k}/(dk)^{3}$ where $ V_{k} = 4 \pi k^{2} dk $ is the volume of the sphere
> and $ (dk)^{3} $ is the volume of a pixel in our Fourier transform
> cube.
>
> So one can estimate how many values one can use to calculate our
> power spectrum for each value of $ k $. The greater the $ k $, the
> greater the number of accessible values and therefore the statistical
> error decreases. The power spectrum is a variance estimator so the
> statistical error is basically a relative error:
>
> $ \dfrac{\sigma (P(k))}{P(k)} = \sqrt{\dfrac{2}{N_{k}
> > -1}}_{\text{with}} N_{k} \approx 4\pi \left (\dfrac{k}{dk}\right)^{2} $
>
> So we can see that for the case $|\vec{k}| = 0$ we have an infinite error because $N_{k} = 1$

1. I can't manage to proove that the statistical error is formulated like :

$\dfrac{\sigma (P (k))}{P(k)} = \sqrt{\dfrac {2}{N_{k} -1}}_{\text{with}} N_{k} \approx 4\pi \left(\dfrac{k}{dk}\right)^{2}$

and why it is considered like a relative error ?

2. Which are the conditions to assimilate a statistical error (standard deviation) to a relative error ($\dfrac{\Delta x}{x}$) ?
3. How to prove that $N_{k} = 1$ in the case $|\vec{k}| = 0$ ?

Any help is welcome.

Comment: Your question on [Physics SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/636387/cosmic-variance-fourier-transform-a-few-precisions) was only posted 14 hours before you cross-posted here.  That's just impatience on your part.  I am particularly confused why you do not simply *ask* your colleague.